# Open server socket in android : permission denied?

Tags: android, sockets, root

I'm trying to create server socket on port 554 (rtsp) in Android and i'm getting `BindException` with 'denied' message:

```
        public RequestListener() throws IOException {
            try {
                mRtspServerSocket = new ServerSocket(mPort);
                start();
            } catch (BindException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Port bind exception");
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Are standard ports (or < 1024) unavailable for binding? Do i have to have root permission on the device for that?

PS. I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to ports <1024.

> Either root your phone, modify the firmware, or don't bind to ports
>   lower than 1024. That's a Linux thing more than an Android thing.

Comment: Not in the official manual yet. You can have a look at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4039 - if you need some official statement I would recommend to search for some Linux source. (If you root your phone, you'll be able to test it with ports <1024, I did this few weeks ago)