# Xamarin Android UDP catch Broadcast from other clients

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm trying to get UDP messages send from clients in network, but when I create a new UdpClient I always get the exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Access denied'

My Code for this very simple and woring perfect on console application, but not in Xamarin App.

```
public void Demo()
        {
            var Server = new UdpClient(80);
            var ResponseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SomeResponseData");

            while (true)
            {
                var ClientEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                var ClientRequestData = Server.Receive(ref ClientEp);
                var ClientRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ClientRequestData);

                Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} from {1}, sending response", ClientRequest, ClientEp.Address.ToString());
                Server.Send(ResponseData, ResponseData.Length, ClientEp);
            }
        }
```

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341860/socketexception-access-denied-while-opening-port-using-udpclient) posting but this did not help me at all.

I'm using Android 11 for testing.

Comment: Have you tried using another local port instead of 80? Is that possible for your scenario?

Comment: Yes, I tried many ports. No difference.

Comment: You can use **try/catch (SocketException.ErrorCode)** to get the specific error code, and then refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2 for details of the error.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Access denied
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint localEP) [0x0003d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:787 
  at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor (System.Int32 port, System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily family) [0x0007e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs:108

Comment: -- at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor (System.Int32 port) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs:73 
  at NetworkScann.BaseUdpReceiver.Demo () [0x00002] in C:\Users\Nils\source\repos\NetworkScan\NetworkScan\BaseUDP.cs:44 }

Comment: When we ask for details, add them to the question. Are you trying to perform network activity on the main UI thread? Be aware that android may drop broadcast traffic as a power saving measure, even if you have a socket listening.

Comment: Can you try without the specified port? just var Server = new UdpClient(). You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420560/unable-to-receive-udp-broadcast-in-xamarin-forms-app), it might help you setting up the UdpCLient with the bind and the socketOptions . Also, do you have specified the permissions in the android.manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another post, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760298/open-server-socket-in-android-permission-denied)
so you cant bind port 80 if you did not root your device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).